# Is there a faster way (than this) to calculate the hash of a file (using hashlib) in Python?

Tags: python, hashlib

My current approach is this:

```
def get_hash(path=PATH, hash_type='md5'):
    func = getattr(hashlib, hash_type)()
    with open(path, 'rb') as f:
         for block in iter(lambda: f.read(1024*func.block_size, b''):
             func.update(block)
    return func.hexdigest()
```

It takes about 3.5 seconds to calculate the md5sum of a 842MB iso file on an i5 @ 1.7 GHz. I have tried different methods of reading the file, but all of them yield slower results. Is there, perhaps, a faster solution?

EDIT: I replaced `2**16` (inside the `f.read()`) with `1024*func.block_size`, since the default `block_size` for most hashing functions supported by hashlib is `64` (except for 'sha384' and 'sha512' - for them, the default `block_size` is `128`). Therefore, the block size is still the same (65536 bits).

EDIT(2): I did something wrong. It takes 8.4 seconds instead of 3.5. :(

EDIT(3): Apparently Windows was using the disk at +80% when I ran the function again. It really takes 3.5 seconds. Phew.

Another solution (~-0.5 sec, slightly faster) is to use os.open():

```
def get_hash(path=PATH, hash_type='md5'):
    func = getattr(hashlib, hash_type)()
    f = os.open(path, (os.O_RDWR | os.O_BINARY))
    for block in iter(lambda: os.read(f, 2048*func.block_size), b''):
        func.update(block)
    os.close(f)
    return func.hexdigest()
```

Note that these results are not final.

Comment: How fast is it to calculate the MD5 of this file using the `md5sum` tool?

Comment: @LutzHorn Since I'm not using a Linux/Gnu distribution at the moment, using Gnu's 32bit md5sum for Windows, it takes 8.5257151 seconds.

Comment: So Python is not that bad :)

Comment: Try using `os.open()` if you aren't using it already.

Comment: @martineau Can you elaborate?

Comment: You have to hunt a little bit to find it in the [os module's](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.open) documentation, but it's a lower level version of the built-in `open()` function that returns a "file object" -- which sounds like some sort of wrapper -- so using the former might incur less overhead.

Comment: P.S. You'll also need to use `os.read()`.

Comment: Try block_size * 32768, which is 2MB.

Comment: @greggo It doesn't change much.

Comment: There is no point in using hashfunc.block_size at all, it's a meaningless value that only exists as part of the APIs for legacy reasons.  Just loop reading whatever size is efficient to read from disk for the purposes of your code and pass it to the hash function.  As long as you read more than ~64KiB at a time you are unlikely to notice any measurable difference.

Comment: @gps Actually there are noticeable differences. Increase or decrease the block_size substantially and your function will run either a few seconds faster or slower.

Comment: My point was that the block_size attribute of the hash functions is entirely useless.  You should not write code that uses it.  Modifying it will do nothing.  The only thing that matters is modifying an I/O buffer size.  That has nothing to do with the hash functions internal block size.

Comment: @gps, I know that. The thing is, I'm not modifying the block_size attribute of the hash function. I'm modifying the I/O buffer size by using the default block_size value (multiplied by some other value) as a parameter.

Comment: My point is that the hash function "block_size" attribute is meaningless and shouldn't even be used for any purpose. Just pick an IO buffer size, don't attempt to base it off of block_size.

Comment: @Deneb What processing time you are aiming at? It seems, like current processing time is close to what is technically possible. Optimizing without clear measurements (which you do) and target result (which I miss here) can soon become endless waste of time.

Comment: @martineau The `open` function is being called once so replacing it with `os.open` will have literally zero effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using an 874 MiB random data file which required 2 seconds with the `md5` openssl tool I was able to improve speed as follows.

- Using your first method required 21 seconds.
- Reading the entire file (21 seconds) to buffer and then updating required 2 seconds.
- Using the following function with a buffer size of 8096 required 17 seconds.
- Using the following function with a buffer size of 32767 required 11 seconds.
- Using the following function with a buffer size of 65536 required 8 seconds.
- Using the following function with a buffer size of 131072 required 8 seconds.
- Using the following function with a buffer size of 1048576 required 12 seconds.

```py
def md5_speedcheck(path, size):
    pts = time.process_time()
    ats = time.time()
    m = hashlib.md5()
    with open(path, 'rb') as f:
        b = f.read(size)
        while len(b) > 0:
            m.update(b)
            b = f.read(size)
    print("{0:.3f} s".format(time.process_time() - pts))
    print("{0:.3f} s".format(time.time() - ats))
```

Human time is what I noted above. Whereas processor time for all of these is about the same with the difference being taken in IO blocking.

The key determinant here is to have a buffer size that is big enough to mitigate disk latency, but small enough to avoid VM page swaps. For my particular machine it appears that 64 KiB is about optimal.

Comment: Is there any way how the buffer size can be chosen automatically?

Comment: Since 3.11, [hashlib has a `file_digest` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html#file-hashing) that is probably a lot faster even than this (untested).

Comment: Hashing usually alternates between blocking on disk IO and blocking on CPU usage so mmap, async, threading, or disk readahead might be helpful